# Why is `where` syntax in Julia sensitive to new-line?

Tags: julia

In a different question on Stack Overflow the answer included the following function:

```
julia> function nzcols(b::SubArray{T,2,P,Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}}}) where {T,P<:SparseMatrixCSC}
           return collect(i+1-start(b.indexes[2]) 
             for i in b.indexes[2]
             if b.parent.colptr[i]<b.parent.colptr[i+1] && 
               inrange(b.parent.rowval[nzrange(b.parent,i)],b.indexes[1]))
       end
nzcols (generic function with 3 methods)
```

And it was parsed without error. When adding a new-line before `where` clause for readability, an error suddenly appeared:

```
julia> function nzcols(b::SubArray{T,2,P,Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}}})
        where {T,P<:SparseMatrixCSC}
           return collect(i+1-start(b.indexes[2]) 
             for i in b.indexes[2]
             if b.parent.colptr[i]<b.parent.colptr[i+1] && 
               inrange(b.parent.rowval[nzrange(b.parent,i)],b.indexes[1]))
       end
ERROR: syntax: space before "{" not allowed in "where {"
```

Finally, when the parameter list parenthesis is moved to the `where` line, the error disappears again:

```
julia> function nzcols(b::SubArray{T,2,P,Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}}}
        ) where {T,P<:SparseMatrixCSC}
           return collect(i+1-start(b.indexes[2]) 
             for i in b.indexes[2]
             if b.parent.colptr[i]<b.parent.colptr[i+1] && 
               inrange(b.parent.rowval[nzrange(b.parent,i)],b.indexes[1]))
       end
nzcols (generic function with 3 methods)
```

What is the logic behind this syntax and should it be fixed?

Comment: If your main concern is readability, I would start using more variables and more whitespace, both vertical and horizontal, something like: https://git.io/v9bL1

Comment: @IsmaelVenegasCastelló True. But too much space is also confusing sometimes. Liked the consts and local vars in your example. But perhaps fewer tab levels and intra-function empty lines would be more readable.

Comment: @DanGetz The code came up in a response to a question of mine. I have edited the codes since but the general idea remains the same. I have afterwards thought that this type of effective functionality on views into sparse matrices is missing in Base (cf https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/21796 ). Do you think it'd be worth opening a PR on Base with these functions (and others like it for reducedim operations)?

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Yep. But I also think we should take a lot of sparse matrix code out of base and into a separate package. Maybe we can start small with SparseUtils.jl, which would collect these faster implementations.

Comment: SparseUtils is a nice idea, but why do you think the sparse code should leave Base? FYI, the functions you helped with currently live here: https://github.com/EcoJulia/SpatialEcology.jl/blob/master/src/Sparse_matrixfunctions.jl

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard There is really a lot of code and tweaks which can be done with sparse (almost every algorithm can have a custom version), and it is rather self-contained. Many users will really have no business with sparse matrices (like system/string/UI people). And Julia should jealously keep the ability to do "core" stuff in packages - actually having them outside core is the only way to keep loose binding. PS This is a discussion for elsewhere (and others too).

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/21796#issuecomment-308130713

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is similar to many other syntaxes in the language; if the parser has a "complete" syntax at the end of a line, it'll use that and move on.

```
julia> parse("begin; 1 \n+ 2; end")
quote  # none, line 1:
    1 # none, line 2:
    +2
end

julia> parse("begin; 1 +\n 2; end")
quote  # none, line 1:
    1 + 2
end
```

Note that this means you can still break the `where` clause onto a separate line, but the `where` itself needs to be on the same line as the end of the function.

Comment: Makes sense. It looks more readable to have the `where` in the second-line, but at least there is logic at work. Maybe it would have been possible to have the `where` inside the parameter list, but it's too late now I guess.

Comment: Where inside the parameter list means something different: instead of creating a static type parameter that spans all arguments (and is accessible within the function), it just creates a local type variable that only applies to that final argument.

Comment: why did Julia switch from `f{x <: T}(x::T)` to `f(x::T) where {x <: T}`? was there any discussion about it?

Comment: The old syntax was confusing with parametric types: it's surprising that `Point{T}(x::T)` creates a function on `Point`, and the ASCII soup required for a function on `Point{T}` was bizarre: `(::Type{Point{T}}){T}(::T)`.  The new syntax makes that clear: `Point(x::T) where T` or `Point{T}(x::T) where T`.  https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/20501#discussion_r99934592