# Method Chaining in Julia

Tags: julia

I read https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5571 which made me think I could break lines like that due to some of the comments:

```
a = [x*5 for x in 0:20 if x>4]

scale(y) = (x)-> y*x
filter(y) = x -> [z for z in x if z>y]

a|>(x->x/3)
    |>scale(2)
    |>filter(4)
    |>println
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: "|>" is not a unary operator
 in include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:488
 in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:265
 in _start() at ./client.jl:321
```

Am I forced to use `a|>(x->x/3)|>scale(2)|>filter(4)|>println`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can move the `|>` operators to the line-ends:

```
julia> a|>(x->x/3)|>
       scale(2)|>
       filter(4)|>
       println
```

This syntax is because the parser needs to decide unambiguously when a statement ends.

(actually, I've asked a question about such an issue myself and got a good answer. see [Why is `where` syntax in Julia sensitive to new-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983787/why-is-where-syntax-in-julia-sensitive-to-new-line))

Comment: This does not work:

    julia> [1:9...] |> filter(4)
    ERROR: MethodError: no method matching filter(::Int64)

Comment: @sirex `filter` is defined in the question. Seems to work on Julia v1.00