# Function chaining in Julia

Tags: julia

Is it possible to write multiple function calls as a chain?

```
sum(
  map(parseIgFloat, 
    map((row) -> row.PL_Amount, 
      filter((row) -> !ismissing(row.Summary) && row.Summary == "Cash In", 
        collect(ts)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Turn it into something like:

```
ts 
  |> collect
  |> filter((row) -> !ismissing(row.Summary) && row.Summary == "Cash In")
  |> map((row) -> row.PL_Amount)
  |> map(parseIgFloat)
  |> sum
```

Comment: Sure. Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44520097/method-chaining-in-julia

Comment: @JongsuLiamKim thanks, but it's not the same, that question has functions with 1 argument only, while here couple of functions like `filter` and `map` with multiple arguments. I would like to find the most compact and nice way to write it.

Answer (score 4):

After searching, this seems to be the best option available

```
ts |> 
  collect |> 
  (list -> filter((row) -> !ismissing(row.Summary) && row.Summary == "Cash In", list)) |>
  (list -> map((row) -> row.PL_Amount, list)) |>
  (list -> map(parseIgFloat, list)) |>
  sum
```

or with the `Pipe` package with the macros

```
@pipe ts |> 
  collect |> 
  filter((row) -> !ismissing(row.Summary) && row.Summary == "Cash In", _) |>
  map((row) -> row.PL_Amount, _) |>
  map(parseIgFloat, _) |>
  sum
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, what you ask is difficult, since whatever construct you came up with, you would have to guarantee the order of arguments as passed is the order expected by the function, so there is no general enough method to allow you to do this without defining explicit types and operations for it.

However, with respect to `map` and `filter` *specifically*, it is trivial to create 'curried' versions of these functions and apply chaining to them. E.g.

```julia
# Create curried versions of map and filter for use in 'chaining'
import Base.map;    function    map(f); return L ->    map(f,L); end;
import Base.filter; function filter(f); return L -> filter(f,L); end;


f  = x -> x ^ 2;
ts = range(1, stop=10);

( ts
  |>  collect          
  |>  map(f)             # square the collection
  |>  filter(iseven)     # keep only even results
  |>  sum              
)
```

Output:

```julia
220
```

---

<sub>PS: Chaining is mostly about ease of readability, and is most useful when you have a succession of individually **simple and visually straightforward commands**, as above. If you're going to have complicated expressions in your 'chain', like the ones in your proposed solution, then it's not really worth it in my opinion. Either wrap your complicated expressions into appropriately named functions that make the chain read like plain english, or avoid chaining in the first place, and rely on clear steps using temporary variables instead.</sub>

<sub>PS2: Also note that, the `|>` operator is a valid target for broadcasting, like any function. Therefore `|> map(f)` above could also have been written more simply as `.|> f` instead.</sub>

Comment: Note, however, that this is [type piracy](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/style-guide/#Avoid-type-piracy-1): adding new methods to `Base.map` that don't use your own types might compose badly with other code.

Comment: @SGJ Agreed. This is just a toy example, proper use of namespacing would be advisable etc, as long as it doesn't hurt readability. Having said that, I'm assuming this is what Stefan was referring to when he said he could envisage a small amount of standard, predefined curried functions (as per the link in one of the other answers here).

Answer (score 1):

I would probably write it like this:

```
sum(row -> parseIgFloat(row.PL_Amount),
    filter((row) -> !ismissing(row.Summary) && row.Summary == "Cash In", 
            ts)
    )
```

If and when underscore currying comes about (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/24990) you could simplify it like this:

```
sum(parseIgFloat(_.PL_Amount)), 
    filter(!ismissing(_.Summary) && _.Summary == "Cash In",  # actually not sure if this line would work
           ts)
    )
```

At that point chaining might also become more convenient.

By the way: don't use `collect` unless you somehow really have to.